# Are these two ways the same for overriding a function?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, nix, nixos

https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/override-design-pattern#id1431 provides a way of overriding a function `f`:

```
rec {
  makeOverridable = f: origArgs:
    let
      origRes = f origArgs;
    in
      origRes // { override = newArgs: makeOverridable f (origArgs // newArgs); };
}
```

Is it the same as:

```
rec {
  makeOverridable = f: origArgs:
    let
      origRes = f origArgs;
    in
      origRes // { override = makeOverridable (newArgs: f (origArgs // newArgs)); };
}
```

?

In particular, are

```
newArgs: makeOverridable f (origArgs // newArgs)
```

and

```
makeOverridable (newArgs: f (origArgs // newArgs))
```

the same?

Are they the same as

```
makeOverridable (makeOverridable f)
```

?